# Как проиграть видео в браузере с ПК?

Tags: mediaplayer, java, servlet

Как можно проиграть видео в браузере, при том что видео находиться на локальной машине.

Может кто стыкался с такой проблемой, какие плееры юзали? Больше интересуют плееры на распространенные форматы. Как их подключать что бы читать файл с локальной машины?
Уже пробовал писать сервлет который возвращает поток, все равно не помагало.

```
package compam.servlets;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import compam.model.Film;
import compam.services.FilmService;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class DownloadService
 */
@WebServlet("/download")
public class DownloadFilm extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

        Film film = new Film();

        film = new FilmService().getFilmById(id);

        String path = film.getFileLink();

        int length = 0;
        File file = new File(path);
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        String mimeType = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getMimeType(
                path);

        response.setContentType((mimeType != null) ? mimeType
                : "application/octet-stream");
        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
                + film.getName().replace(" ", "_") + "\"");

        byte[] bbuf = new byte[4096];
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
            outputStream.write(bbuf, 0, length);
        }
        in.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

}
```

Кто знает как решить такую проблему?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript плееры Вас не устроят?

Comment: наверное устроят, но я просто не смог настроить на вещание с локалхоста

Comment: Эмм, а какая разница откуда, если вещание через браузер? Вам нужно погуглить на эту тему.

Answer (score 0):

Сразу скажу, что не сталкивалась с подобным, но вопрос заинтересовал.
Все, чем пока могу помочь, это [Потоковое аудио/видео вещание с VideoLAN](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/253/253r.shtml). Там же сказано, что можно

> использовать VideoLAN в качестве обычного медиа-плеера

Сайт программы [VideoLan](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.php?cat=video).
Еще есть [DivX Browser Plugin](http://gizmod.ru/2006/01/08/plagin_dlja_prosmotra_filmov_v_brauzere/), но я не уточняла, можно ли при помощи этой утилиты видео смотреть с сайтов или с компа.

Comment: спасибо, гляну - отпишусь )

Comment: Не работает)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать использовать [Vaadin](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#FlashEmbed). Примерно так:

```
package com.vaadin.demo.sampler.features.embedded;

import com.vaadin.terminal.FileResource;
import com.vaadin.ui.Embedded;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FlashEmbedExample extends VerticalLayout {

    public FlashEmbedExample() {
        File file = new File("/home/user/file.flv");
        Embedded e = new Embedded(null, new FileResource(file, getApplication());
        e.setMimeType("application/x-shockwave-flash");
        e.setParameter("allowFullScreen", "true");
        e.setWidth("320px");
        e.setHeight("265px");
        addComponent(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: он будет поддерживать к примеру avi, mpeg, mp4?

Comment: Я думаю нет

Comment: Естественно нет, указан мими-тип - флэш